# Command to recognise delimiter and split the content in seperate cells of excel

Tags: linux, excel, shell

I am trying to get the output of file which has "#####" as a separator, I want these contents (before and after # separator) to be printed in separate cells of excel. I have attached the data as of now and my requirement in next screenshot.I am new to shell scripting , I have tried to use below code to get the data which present now and I am not able to proceed further to check for separator.

[Data required](https://i.stack.imgur.com)

[Data as of now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPAbX.png)/SiCuU.png

Code used until now:

```
. /data/shellscripts/Consumer_Macros.Include
rm -f /data/shellscripts/essbase/Operate/Overlays/rules*.txt
for i in $(cat apps.txt);
do
cd /local/apps/oracle/Middleware/user_projects/epmsystem1/EssbaseServer/essbaseserver1/app/$i
echo $i >> /data/shellscripts/essbase/Operate/Overlays/rules1.txt
done
for i in $(ls *.rul);
do
echo $i  >> /data/shellscripts/essbase/Operate/Overlays/rules1.txt
strings $i  >> /data/shellscripts/essbase/Operate/Overlays/rules.txt
echo '####################################' >> /data/shellscripts/essbase/Operate/Overlays/rules.xls
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the rest of your code, and focusing solely on the logic required to recognise a delimiter, you could do something like so (this is assuming you're reading the file into a variable or something similar):

`output=$(echo $EXCELFILE | tr "#####")`

That should delimit by '`####`'